# After change font size in device setting app ui is deformed

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My application was working without problems until the user changed the font size of the phone and increased its size
With this font change, all the software became bigger and I don't know what changes I should make in the app to be able to manage this change.
Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: I think we need a screen shot or some code in order to help you.

Comment: Provide screenshot so anyone can understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can set their own font size preferences on the device, and that scaling factor is used in *sp* units, which is *dp* multiplied by the current font scaling. That's why you (usually) use *sp* when setting font sizes instead of *dp*, so it adapts to the user's preferences and looks consistent with other apps.

Which means it's something you have to test when you're designing your layout! Set the emulator/device's text size to the largest and smallest values, and make sure it looks ok. And do the same on the smallest screen size you support (the layout editor lets you preview other screen sizes too). If you're [building your layout as a responsive design](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes#responsive_design) then you can make sure the layout adapts nicely to the available space, and that includes when `TextView`s get bigger.

This is an accessibility feature, and you need to cater for those larger sizes in case some of your users need it, so this is something you need to handle. Space is always at a premium on mobile devices, and *personally* I feel like it's ok to let the extremely large sizes look a little less slick - if the user needs huge text they probably care more about functionality than aesthetics, right? So I feel like it's ok to let the huge sizes fill space, eat into margins etc. *if necessary*.

Another thing you can do is look at your writing - if a text label is a problem when it's at a larger text size, maybe the label's text is too long anyway? Short, concise labels don't need to grow as much, and you'll have more space to work with. [Here's the Material style guide](https://m2.material.io/design/communication/writing.html) if it helps (don't forget this applies to translations too!)

And finally, I said for text you *mostly* use *sp* - but if you have any elements that *shouldn't* resize, you can use *dp* to get a fixed real-world size on every screen. This only applies to elements that are **large enough that everyone can read them**, and that don't need to scale relative to the other text. Graphical elements, basically - like how a clock app displays the digits at a fixed size. If that applies in your design anywhere, you can use *dp* to get a fixed size that works for everyone